# I accidentally removed the texture paint window on the left and now I can't continue,

Tags: texture-painting, customization

I removed the window where you actually paint the textures (not painting the model but the image) and now I can't continue, how can I get the screen back

Comment: You can split the existing 3d Editor into two editors and then change one into an Image Editor - hover your mouse at the top right corner and you should see the option available when you drag the corner of the editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can press the plus button and select Texture Paint under general.[image]